# sony remote camera api to to do (Exposure) Bracketing with RAW pictures

Tags: camera, sony

I am a happy Nex-6 user, almost that is...
because i would like to remotely do a bracketing sequence in RAW files for HDR processing.

First i purchased the IR remote, BUT i can either activate remote control OR bracketing in the shooting mode on the camera....

Then i saw the in-camera apps ... no RAW support

Then i found the PlayMemories app on my sony xperia Z1.. but no solution either.
Finally there was camera remote API, v1 was very basic
Now v2 is better and i could develop a java program (currently on windows but planned to develop for android) to take pictures.

I see the methods to change exposure compensation, but i get an error 403 ...

Is there a chance that 
1. the API will be available
2. PlayMemories app will add Bracketing function on RAW files
3. in-camera app will save RAW pictures
?

Best Regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your feedback.
You can shoot RAW+JPEG picture using API when you set still quality setting to RAW+JPEG in camera body setting menu. The RAW file will be stored in memory card. The API currently does NOT fetch RAW file, only fetches JPEG.

Best Regards, Prem, Member of Developer World team at Sony